# Section background overflowing into another section

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I apologize in advance for this somewhat lengthy explanation. I am trying to create a website such as http://melaniedaveid.com/ to improve my coding abilities. I created the first section page and it turned out great. But when I added another section, the previous section didn't fill up the whole page anymore (picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3r5v.jpg).

In order to solve this I gave full height to the first sections ID:

```
#header {
height: 100%;}
```

This fixed the problem(https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YNVz.jpg) but now when I resize my browser the second section over flows into my first, covering the text(https://i.stack.imgur.com/TowAk.jpg). Any suggestions/leads would be greatly appreciated!

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url('/img/roses.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 100vh;
}

/*------------------------------------------------  HOME PAGE  ------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*------------------------------
HEADING TEXT
-------------------------------*/
.name h1 {
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
  font-size: 500%;
  font-weight: 300;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10%;
  color: #ecf0f1;
  font-family: 'Cormorant Garamond', serif;
}

.name p {
  font-family: 'Play', sans-serif;
  font-size: 130%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 5%;
  color: #ecf0f1;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding-right: 10%;
  padding-left: 10%;
}

/*------------------------------
Nav Bar
-------------------------------*/

.navigation p {
  display: inline;
  font-family: 'Play', sans-serif;
  color: #ecf0f1;
}

.navigation {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15%;
}

.contents,
.contents:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ecf0f1;
  font-family: 'Delius Unicase', cursive;
}

/*------------------------------------------------  ABOUT PAGE  ------------------------------------------------------------------*/

/*------------------------------
About Heading
-------------------------------*/

#about {
  background-color: black;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;

}

#header {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section id="header">  <!-------------------------  HOME PAGE  -------------------------->


  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 name">
        <h1>Temple Naylor</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 name">
        <p>I create Web-designs with a sense of Feng-Shui in mind; resulting for a intuitive, responsive, harmonious, experience for users across the world.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 navigation hidden-sm-down">
        <p><a class="contents" href="#">ABOUT</a> / </p>
        <p><a class="contents" href="#">WORK</a> / </p>
        <p><a class="contents" href="#">CONTACT</a> / </p>
        <p><a class="contents" href="#">PHOTOGRAPHY</a></p>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>


<section id="about">  <!-------------------------  ABOUT PAGE  -------------------------->


  <div class="container">
    <div class="row about">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <p class="big-text"></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 about-text">
        <p >Yup</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: When I did such kind of work, I used jquery to set a `section` height depending on viewport dimensions.

Comment: Try to change `#header` `height` to `min-height`: `#header {
  min-height: 100%;
}`. Is it what you need?

Comment: @Banzay this worked perfectly! Thank you so much. Next time leave an actual answer so I can mark you correct. I think next time I'm going to use jquery to make this simpler.

Comment: I've copied a comment to the answers section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change #header height to min-height:

```
#header { 
    min-height: 100%; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use css `vh` property for this.

```
#header {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

here is more info about [css units](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp). Hope this helps you.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work, ended up figuring out the solution was min-height: 100%;  Will give you a check for the helpful article though since you are the only answer on this post(: